# Error returning a list of user-defined objects from a function in C++

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, allocator

*Background*

I have written a class `Str` that mimics string operations, for instructional purposes. The class `Str` is an array of characters in essence.

I created a function `makeList` that receives a `Str` object, creates a list of `Str` objects using `push_back` and returns the list.

I am using `allocators`, but I have tightened the memory management to allocate only enough memory for the characters created.

*Problem*

- Compilation, linking, and run-time produce no errors.
- The list object content is OK when viewed within `MakeList` using `cout << ret.back()`.
- The problem is that the objects within the list have garbage input overwriting the first ~10 characters when viewed in the `main` body.
- I have also verified that the `Str` I create are being destroyed via the default destructor.

I have included the minimum amount of code to replicate the problem.

*Non-class code:*

```
list<Str> makeList(const Str s)
    {
        list<Str> ret;
        ret.push_back(s);
        cout << ret.back() << endl;

        return ret;
    }

    int main() {

        Str greeting = "Hello world";
        list<Str> result;
        result = makeList(greeting);
        result.pop_front();
        cout << "The result is " << result.front() << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

*Class code:*

```
class Str {
    friend std::istream& operator>>(istream&, Str&);
public:
    typedef char* iterator;
    typedef const char* const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef char value_type;

    Str() { create(); } // default constructor

    Str(const_iterator cp, const_iterator cp2) {
        create(cp, cp2);
    }
    Str(const_iterator cp) {
        create(cp, cp + strlen(cp));
    }
    ~Str() {uncreate(); }

    char& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
    const char& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }

    Str& operator=(const Str& s) {
        uncreate();
        create(s.begin(), s.end());
    };

    Str substr(size_type i, size_type d) const {
        const_iterator cStart, cTerm;
        cStart = this->begin() + i;
        cTerm  = this->begin() + i + d;
        Str sub(cStart, cTerm);
        cout << "Pointer diff = " << sub.limit - sub.data << endl;
        return sub;
    }

    size_type size() const { return avail - data; }

    iterator begin() { return data; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return data; }

    iterator end() { return avail; }
    const_iterator end() const { return avail; }


private:
    iterator data;
    iterator avail;
    iterator limit;

    allocator<char> alloc;

    void create();
    void create(const_iterator, const_iterator);

    void uncreate();

};

void Str::create()
{
    data = avail = limit = 0;
}

void Str::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j)
{
    data = alloc.allocate(j - i);
    limit = avail = uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
}

void Str::uncreate()
{
    if (data) {
        iterator it = avail;
        while (it != data)
            alloc.destroy(--it);

        alloc.deallocate(data, limit - data);
    }

    data = limit = avail = 0;
    cout << "UNCREATED" << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Str& s) {
    for (Str::size_type i = 0; i != s.size(); i++)
        os << s[i];
    return os;

}
```

Comment: So, where's the copy/move constructor? It is called e.g. by `list<Str>::push_back` The compiler-generated one will not do what you want (shallow copy). Please follow either the rule of three (rule of five in C++11) or the rule of zero.

Comment: Thank you. That may explain it. I read through documentation for the push_back operation online but could not find what it required from a user-defined object. I was not sure that was the issue since the push_back operation created an apparently suitable list with the cout in the makeList function.

Comment: The textbook I'm using, AcceleratedC++, overall is excellent but did not have a copy constructor either in it's original Str definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, you are missing a copy constructor for `Str`, but you do call it here :

```
 result2 = makeList(greeting); // Pass by value -> copy
```

And here :

```
 ret.push_back(s);  // Pass by value -> copy
```

Without it, the default copy constructor is used, but it's not doing what you want.
Possible implementation :

```
Str(const Str& other) 
{
    create(other.begin(), other.end());
}
```

Always respect [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: The `Str` passed by value calls the copy ctor.

Comment: For a short moment, I didn't realize the `list` within `make_list` :) -- in C++11, this will use the move assignment-operator of `list`, AFAIK.